# How to extract IPv6 field attribute values from the header present in hexadecimal string value in a file using Python?

Tags: python, hex, extract, slice, ipv6

An IPv6 header has the following value :

```
68 01 00 00 31 02 FF 2A 01 3F 4D 9C 7E 11 14 56 19 DE A0 BD CD 17 FF CD DF 01 03 04 BC 2B 3A 4E 9D AB DE 9D AE 07 FF (IN TXT FILE)
```

After removing white spaces:

```
680100003102FF2A013F4D9C7E11145619DEA0BDCD17FFCDDF010304BC2B3A4E9DABDE9DAE07FF
```

The above header is present in a file and I'm trying to extract all the field attributes present in the string as mentioned in the picture.

Here the picture contains header field attribute details:

[image: img]

I tried slicing and checking if the value falls below the upper limit(by using byte size) but it doesn't work when alphabets (in the hex format) come into the picture.

Is there any optimal and error-free way to do this generically in python?

Comment: You seem to be off. For example, the payload length is two bytes (four nibbles) that is actually `3102`, not `31`, so you are off by one byte starting there. Also, the entire header you have is one byte short in the full header you have because you only have 39 bytes (78 nibbles), but an IPv6 packet header length is always 40 bytes (80 nibbles).

Comment: @RonMaupin Thank you! That solves everything!